# How to disable JavaScript alert in lime survey validation

Tags: javascript, limesurvey

While filling the questionnaire a JavaScript alert occurs when a mandatory question or validation error found. After alert a read message displayed which looks good but alert annoys.
Is there any way to disable alert throughout the Survey?

In Lime survey it is different to place code for java script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newAlert = alert; // Preserving alert.

// Overriding the default alert.
alert = function(str){
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes.It works fine. Thanks void.
Hope it will work for all browsers.

Comment: @PHPBeginner how could this work while the identical code from the other answer did not?

Comment: @void voting up requires 15 reputations but i have 11 currently. Will up vote when equal to 15

Comment: @zerkms you need to pass the argument, `alert` takes an string argument.

Comment: @void you don't. Your code is identical to the `alert = function(){};` (which is suggested in the other answer) as per the standard. There is no way these 2 functions to behave differently. You don't use the `str` variable so it might be omitted. The same for `return`.

Answer (score 0):

try this once . IT will disable all alerts.
`alert = function() {};`

Comment: Thanks Shubham for Answer but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: where are you using this function ??

Comment: Using in Limesurvey Question source.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3gu6veo8/1/ ... this is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update application/config/config.php :

```
    'config'=>array(
        'debug'=>0,
        'showpopups'=>0,
    )
```

https://manual.limesurvey.org/Optional_settings#Survey_Behavior